# Рефакторинг отработки нажатий, копирования кнопок

Tags: java, android

Есть у меня порядка 15 кнопок, при нажатии на каждую создается её копия с новыми параметрами. В принципе он одинаков на 90%, но для каждой кнопки есть свои параметры (задаются в коде, динамических нет).
Подскажите, как можно улучшить код. Можно ли сделать его универсальным, а не прописывать полностью все в ручную? Все работает, но хочется более красивый и функциональный код.

```
       public void ClickButton1(View v){

        copy_pr1 = new Button(getApplicationContext());
        copy_pr1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.newpate);
        copy_pr1.setText(pr1.getText().toString() );
        copy_pr1.setId(USERID + countID);
        Colo.addView(copy_pr1);
        countID++;
        final ObjectAnimator button_copy_button1 = ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(copy_pr1,
                PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("x", ListCoordinateX_1.get(0)),
                PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("y", LineY_1.get(0)));
        button_copy_button1.setDuration(1500);
        button_copy_button1.start();

        ListCoordinateX_1.remove(0);

        MainListWord.add(pr1.getText().toString());
        pr1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.acceptbutton);
        pr1.setEnabled(false);
        textSee.setText(String.valueOf(MainListWord));

        button_copy_button1.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                button_copy_button1.ofFloat(copy_pr1, "alpha", 0f).setDuration(600).start();
            }
            @Override
            public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {
            }
        });
        SwitchTextField();
        ListXUpFull();

    } //кнопка 1
```

Comment: GПосмотреть в сторону RecyclerView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Создайте модельку которая будет в себе хранит параметры каждой кнопки. Создайте себе список из этих моделей, где каждый элемент это кнопка. И отобразите этот список с помощью RecyclerView. Если вам понадобится добавить новую кнопку. То просто добавляете новый элемент в список, передаете новый список в RecyclerView и обновляете адаптер.